# start antd RangePicker (datepicker) week from monday instead of sunday

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, antd, daterangepicker

i am using antd RangePicker to get start and end value of date. my calanders starts from sunday but i want to start it from monday

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6RLz.png)

i have try this solution but nothing works

```
import { LocaleProvider, Calendar } from 'antd';
import en_GB from 'antd/lib/locale-provider/en_GB';
<LocaleProvider locale={en_GB}>
<Calendar
    dateFullCellRender={dateFullCellRender}
    onSelect={this.onSelect}
    defaultValue={this.state.selectedDate}
    ...
/></LocaleProvider>
```

Answer (score 3):

The [antd doc](https://ant.design/components/date-picker#how-to-modify-start-day-of-week) doesn't work for me.

This works for me:

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import updateLocale from 'dayjs/plugin/updateLocale';

dayjs.extend(updateLocale)
dayjs.updateLocale('en', {
    weekStart: 1
})
```

Answer (score 0):

From antd documentation [here](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/)

```
import 'moment/locale/en-gb';
import locale from 'antd/es/locale/en_GB';
import moment from 'moment';

moment.locale('en-gb', {
  week: {
    dow: 1 /// Date offset
  }
});
```

EDIT:
Seems that after a few years, the way of doing this has changed (Again according to the linked documentation), now it should be done this way:

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import 'dayjs/locale/en_GB';
import 'dayjs/plugin/updateLocale';

dayjs.updateLocale('en_gb', {
  weekStart: 0,
});
```

Comment: I have used this in my app.js for WebPack:
import 'moment/locale/ru';
import moment from 'moment';

moment().locale('ru', {
  week: {
    dow: 1 /// Date offset
  }
});

Comment: Does it work for u? which version of antd are u using

Comment: @donquixote take a look at edited answer

Comment: @J.Salas thanks for quick response. Unfortunately this doesn't work. Probable antd side should fix it